# can't figure out why I am getting a segmentation fault initializing my array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which works fine for N=10 and C=25 but bombs with a segmentation fault if I use N=50 and C=25500

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// create table
int *table;
table  = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * C+1 * N+1);
if(table == NULL){
  printf("[ERROR] : Fail to allocate memory.\n");
}

// initialize table
for(i =0; i < N-1; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < C-1; j++){
    //table[i*(C+1)+j]=0;
    *(table + (i*(C+1)+j))=1;
  }
}
printf("table made\n");
```

Comment: So this works without a `main()`?

Comment: Make sure the math is correct inside of malloc, (you may mean (C+1)*(N+1))

Comment: where did you got the segmentation fault error? put printf statements inside for loop and try to find out at which location u got the segmentation fault..Because if malloc does not allocate any memory for large numbers we can find out in the `if(table == NULL)` condition. Pls try this

Comment: A good tool to help with this kind of problems is valgrind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the amount of memory you are allocating is incorrect. You are allocating `C*sizeof(int) + N + 1` and you want to be allocating `(C+1)*(N+1)*sizeof(int)`
You're just missing some parens -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: ugg.   I should have seen that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming int = 4 so you allocate

```
4*50 + 1*25500 + 1 = 25701 bytes
```

In your loop you access (at the end):

```
i = 49
j = 25499

49*(25501)+25499 = 1275048(index)*4 = 5100192 (offset)
```

So what you need is:

```
 table  = malloc(sizeof(int) * (C+1) * (N+1));
```

Your loop didn't work for smaller values either, it just didn't crash. Writing outside allocated memory is undefined behaviour.

And as a sidenote, not related to your crash:
[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)